# vectorization with pandas series - multiple 'complex' boolean categorisations - run time optimisation

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, vectorization

As I process more and more data, the apply function I use is now to slow for my projets. I use really often vectorization in my work but for some function I tryed without success (yet).

**The question is:
How to vectorize this function containing multiple decision?**

Please found here a not optimised code sample (using apply):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def what_should_eat_that_cat(row):
    start_ = row[0]<=500
    end_ = row[1] <=500  
    miaw = row[2]<=200

    if start_ & end_:
        if miaw:
            return 'cat1'
        else:
            return 'cat2'        
    if start_ & ~end_:
        return 'cat3'   
    if ~start_ & end_:
        return 'cat4'
    else :
        return 'cat5'

start_time = time.time()

df.loc[:,'eat_cat'] = df.loc[:,['A','B','C']].apply(what_should_eat_that_cat,axis=1)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This take 16 seconds to process for 100k lines.

The result should be somethings like:

df.eat_cat =>
0    cat5
1    cat5
2    cat3
3    cat5
4    cat4

Here is my progress so far.

```
def what_should_eat_that_cat(A,B,C):
    start_ = A <=500
    end_ = B <=500  
    miaw = C <=200

    if start_ & end_:
        if miaw:
            return 'cat1'
        else:
            return 'cat2'        
    if start_ & ~end_:
        return 'cat3'   
    if ~start_ & end_:
        return 'cat4'
    else :
        return 'cat5'

df.loc[:,'eat_cat'] = what_should_eat_that_cat(df.A, df.B, df.C)
```

I get this error: **The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**
I understand why. But I do not get how to vectorize anyway.

Here is some documentation about vectorization:
https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6
According to this webste, this operation may run 50x faster.

Comment: you're doing `start_ & end_`thinking about `True & True`. But you're passing Series. Instead of calling a function and passing the dataframe's columns as parameters, use `df.apply` and use your function as parameter

Comment: @Yuca: I agree with what you say but I have the impression that if I use apply, it will work but I increase my computing time again. I would like to completely vectorize this function to save computing time.

Comment: the reason why I'm writing a comment is to shed light on your error. If I had a solution I would write as an answer :) The `df.apply` is a suggestion that would help you overcome the error of ambiguous value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to go 52x faster:

```
def categ(dataframe):
    start_ = dataframe.A <=500
    end_ = dataframe.B <=500  
    miaw = dataframe.C <=200

    #we treat each case separately in a vectorial way
    dataframe.loc[start_ & end_ & miaw, 'cat'] = 'cat1'
    dataframe.loc[start_ & end_ & ~miaw, 'cat'] = 'cat2'
    dataframe.loc[start_ & ~end_, 'cat'] = 'cat3'
    dataframe.loc[~start_ & end_, 'cat'] = 'cat4'
    dataframe.loc[~start_ & ~end_, 'cat'] = 'cat5'

    return dataframe.cat


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

start_time = time.time()
df.loc[:,'eat_cat'] = categ (df)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This take 0.3 sec instead of 16 seconds (with apply).
I hope this will help other that struggle as me on this.